# What is rwfs filesystem?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

I did a df on my embedded device and saw that the one of the filesystems mentioned was rwfs. What is rwfs ?

```
df
Filesystem           1k-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rwfs                     32768       312     32456   1% /var
```

Comment: Does Google help at all here?

Comment: Perhaps the output of the `mount(8)` command can be enlightening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's a tmpfs instance](http://final-world-domination.blogspot.com/2009/11/read-only-root-filesystem-on-embedded.html), as the output of `mount` will have told you.

Comment: yes mount o/p tells it.

Answer (score 3):

Google helps here... **rwfs filesystem**

http://code.google.com/p/leviathanv/wiki/RWFS

To quote...

> RWFS is a filesystem specifically designed to hold large amounts of data(500 Million EB). It accomplishes this by add further dividing disks into large blocks called blocksections. Their size is determined by the block size used

Comment: Unless he is running the "Leviathan OS", that link does not seem relevant...

Comment: It's on an (to us) unknown embedded device, so it's a fair enough suggestion. I think the downvote is unwarranted.

Comment: Just for the record, I did not downvote you.

Comment: I didn't think you did, a driveby-lurker has clearly "great commented" you and downvoted me.  **Thank you oh wise and constructive lurker.**

Comment: you're right, I should have added my own comment when downvoting. My apologies. abc tagged his question with [tag:linux], which seemed obvious enough to me. Furthermore, there's no actual source available to download for the Leviathanv OS, making it less likely that a user is even running it. And for an early adopter of a hobby OS to be asking a question _here_ about something only a handful of people in the world could even run seems even less likely.